# Is there any way to display multiple datasets without comparing option in amchart?

Tags: amcharts

[Here is my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/madhab452/8jze1z72)!

I dont want to show compare to block and i tried with making comaparable to false, but this didn't work.

```
"stockGraphs": [ {
  "id": "g1",
  "valueField": "value",
  "comparable": false,
  "compareField": "value",
  "balloonText": "[[title]]:<b>[[value]]</b>",
  "compareGraphBalloonText": "[[title]]:<b>[[value]]</b>"
} ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set [`compared`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/DataSet#compared) to true in your other datasets (ignore the first one as it is always displayed by default) to show the datasets without using the selector:

```
  "dataSets": [ {
      "title": "first data set",
      "fieldMappings": [ {
        "fromField": "value",
        "toField": "value"
      }, {
        "fromField": "volume",
        "toField": "volume"
      } ],
      "dataProvider": chartData1, 
      //don't set compared in the first dataset or it will be displayed twice
      "categoryField": "date"
    }, {
      "title": "second data set",
      "fieldMappings": [ {
        "fromField": "value",
        "toField": "value"
      }, {
        "fromField": "volume",
        "toField": "volume"
      } ],
      "dataProvider": chartData2,
      "compared": true,
      "categoryField": "date"
    },
    // ... etc
```

If you want to display the other datasets without the percent change, set [`recalculateToPercents`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/StockPanel#recalculateToPercents) to `"never"` in your desired panel(s) or globally in [`panelsSettings`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/PanelsSettings#recalculateToPercents).

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8jze1z72/1/)

*Edit*

If you're looking to just hide the "Compare To": section, add the following CSS:

```
.amcharts-compare-div {
  display: none;
}

/* hide the br tags before and after the dropdown, brining the compare to box up */
.amcharts-data-set-selector-div br:first-child, .amcharts-data-set-selector-div br+select+br, .amcharts-data-set-selector-div br+select+br+br {
  display: none;
}
```

You also need to set the dataSetSelector's `compareText` property to an empty string.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8jze1z72/2/)

Comment: Well that was a nice hack. But it doesnot displays slect options and all the datasets are selected by default. @xorspark

Comment: So you are a developer @amchart. Do you know is there any other chart which satisfy my need Other than this. Multiple datasets without comparision options, but select option.

Comment: I removed the dataSetSelector because I thought that's what you wanted. You can add that back in if you want while keeping the others selected. What are you trying to do exactly? Also I'm not a developer, just support.

Comment: If you're looking to just hide the compare box and the compare text, you can use CSS to hide the compare box and set `compareText` to an empty string inside the dataSetSelector. Check the updated answer

Comment: Thats exactly what i needed.